# fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, nsurl, nsbundle, audio-player

I'm trying out some basic stuff like playing audio.

Right in the beginning when I ran the project I got an error, the error doesn't show up in the view controller but it pops up right away when I run the project.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

My code:

```
var buttonAudioURL = try? NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sound", ofType: "m4a")!)
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation? It's all in the error. You used `!` on a `nil` value and that's not allowed in Swift (see the NSBundle part).

Comment: Convention on SO is if you found an answer useful, upvote it; if you found an answer that helped you solve your problem, mark it as "accepted" (checkmark button under the votes button). You haven't done this ever - not fair. :)

Answer (score 2):

With `NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sound", ofType: "m4a")!` you are *forcing* the unwrapping of the Optional returned by NSBundle (note the `!` at the end).

So if this resource "Sound.m4a" is unavailable, as it seems to be the case, the app will crash.

You need two things: make sure that the resource is in the bundle, and use safe unwrapping and error handling instead of force-unwrapping.

I strongly suggest you read the [nice docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309) Apple has made available for us, all of this is explained in detail.

Also note that `NSURL` doesn't throw so you don't have to use `try` with it.

**Update**

Here's an example of what I'm talking about:

```
if let soundResourceURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Sound", ofType: "m4a") {
    let buttonAudioURL = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: soundResourceURL)
    // use buttonAudioURL here
} else {
    print("Unable to find Sound.m4a")
}
```